Mautic installation fails because not enough memory for npm
So, I'm trying to install Mautic on shared hosting (Debian GNU/Linux 11), but when I try to run composer create-project mautic/recommended-project:^5 newsletter --no-interaction the installation process fails when npm is run with the following error:
> npm ci --prefer-offline --no-audit

#
# Fatal process out of memory: Zone
#
----- Native stack trace -----

<--- Last few GCs --->

[3932986:0x65b1000]      156 ms: Scavenge 8.7 (11.5) -> 7.6 (12.2) MB, pooled: 0 MB, 1.53 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure; 
[3932986:0x65b1000]      239 ms: Scavenge 9.2 (12.2) -> 8.1 (12.7) MB, pooled: 0 MB, 1.56 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure; 
[3932986:0x65b1000]      271 ms: Scavenge 10.2 (12.7) -> 9.0 (13.5) MB, pooled: 2 MB, 1.75 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure; 

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'St9bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
Script npm ci --prefer-offline --no-audit handling the npm-ci event returned with error code 134
Script @npm-ci was called via post-update-cmd

How can I increase memory without root access for the short time that I need to run the installation?
npm -v = 10.9.0, node -v = v22.11.0
free -m returns:
               total        used        free      shared buffer/cache available
Memory:       192061       44893        5549       31856      141618      114710
Swap:            263         263           0

